# What are the uses of tzatziki sauce?

Tags: greek-cuisine, tzatziki

I normally add tzatziki sauce when I eat roast left-overs. I cut the roast in slices (without warming it), and I add some tzatziki sauce.

Are there different uses for tzatziki sauce?  (I am sure there are.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use it on its own as a dip with pita bread, use it as a spread on sandwiches, or as an accompaniment to fish and meat as you're already doing.

Comment: Would it work on vegetable salads too?

Comment: Yes it would, I find that you can use tzatiki any place you would use sour cream as well.

Comment: Mix your tzatziki with some chunked up tomatoes, onions, bell peppers,and cucumbers and you'll have a excellent salad!

Answer (score 4):

It's great added to flatbread wraps made with Greek or Turkish style kebabs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the hardcore traditional rules, but for me, I can use it on absolutely everything, and when I am in Greece I do:

- In addition to salad with bread
- Alone with bread
- As a dip with meat and bread
- As a spread on bread
- Alone, as a side / antipasti for drinks
- In Kebab
- Together with Mousaka
- With fried / baked zucchini
- Watered down as a cold summer soup (Bulgarian Style)
- With crackers
- ...